# Creating a database system for a high school containing students records

Tags: mysql, database

I am building a student database for a high school. I have been able to solve most of my problems with the exception of one.

The tables I currently have are for records of the current school term. I am trying to find a way to permanently keep records for the first term, second term, third term and even after the student graduates. Student information will still be stored in the database permanently.

Please can anyone give me an idea of how I should build it?

Answer (score 2):

Add a field "Term", where you write the term, which this record is for.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most logical way is to have **Year** (calendar year) and **Term** (semester term: Spring, Summer, Fall) fields associated to each student. This way you could fully distinguish attendance by either calendar year or term. For graduation status you could add either graduation flag or graduation date, or both.

**ADDED:**

In response to comment below. Yes, I think it does make more sense to track prospective students and enrolled academic students separately. You either can track those in a stand along table or implement additional fields to the existing table. As an example, you could have a field **person_status** as *enrolled*, *graduated*, *prospective*.

Your ultimate structure really depends on what level of detail you try to achieve.

Comment: Thanks,that's a good idea,but how about the incoming or prospective students(thus new group of students coming in a different year),am i suppose to build tables for them or there can be a different way to do this?

Comment: I've amended my response. Please see above.